# Make Div Class Hover On Page Load

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need a `div` to be `on hover state` when the page loads.

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementByClassName('project-1').className = 'hover';
};
</script>
```

The `css & html` are done like this,

```
<div class="projects-2">

      <div class="project-1">
      </div>
      <div class="project-2">
      </div>     
      <div class="project-3">
      </div>

</div>

.projects-2 > *:hover {
  opacity: 100;
  filter: alpha(opacity=10000);
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

I was assuming if I single out 
`.project-1` like this,

```
.project-1 *:hover {
  opacity: 100;
  filter: alpha(opacity=10000);
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

I could use the `JS` I showed as an example to get this to work. 
But no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please add a fiddle? I kinda didn't understand what are you requesting :)

Comment: your CSS is applying a `psuedo` class of `:hover`, and you are applying a classname of `hover`.. so you'll need to change your css to be something like `.project-1.hover` to correctly apply the styles

Comment: @Linial can do better than a fiddle, On this page I want the first box to be hover on when the page loads then when you hover to another box the page acts as normal from there on out. http://www.wuno.com/lpi/

Comment: @haxxxton would you mind showing me the best way to do this with the css I showed you? I have not worked with anything like this before. *:hover. I know its saying *- All things that hover in projects-2 do this stuff... But how can I add the hover state to project-1 which is in projects-2 on page load?

Comment: you currently have `.project-1 *:hover`.. change this to `.project-1.hover, .project-1:hover`.. if you want this to work for all items in projects-2 do something like: `.projects-2 > div:hover, .projects-2 > .hover`

Comment: Can you not just post an answer

Comment: So your basically saying if I change my `css hover class` to `.projectHover` then my `JS` to `document.getElementByClassName('project-1').className = 'projectHover';` That should work? Cause nothing happens when I do that...

Comment: I don't know what are you trying to achieve. You wanted a hover state but adding a `className` to it. Also you have spelling error in `getElementsByClassName`. The **s** is missing on your code. Please try to be more specific when you ask a question.

Comment: This is the first line of my question, `I need a div to be on hover state when the page loads.` How is that confusing to you?

Comment: You are trying to add a classname using JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your given HTML:

JS

```
<script>
   window.onload = function() {
      document.querySelector('.project-1').className += " page-load-hover";

      document.querySelector('.projects-2').onmouseover=function(){
          var el = this.querySelector('.page-load-hover');
          el.className = el.className.replace(" page-load-hover", "");
      };
   }
</script>
```

CSS

```
.projects-2 > div:hover, .page-load-hover {
    opacity: .4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9979J/

Comment: No problem. EDIT: I updated it with an improved version, that allows you to do add other classes to `.project-1`.

Comment: Thanks a ton I was still confused fixing this. But with this answer I can just change the css and the js and it should work?

Comment: Thank you so much man. I thought I was out of luck based on the comments I was getting.

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with using Django this can be pretty easily done with following:-

In your view create following:

```
def abc(request):
      context = {
           'content_type':'None'
       }
      response = render(request, "index.html", context)
      return response
```

In your template(index.html) the div you want to make hover by default do following using the if condition:-

```
   <div class='col-md-3 sub-heading {% if content_type == "None" %}active{% endif %}'><a href="#">all</a></div>
```

Put in following in the CSS :-

```
.sub-heading.active a{
color:#191919 !Important;
font-weight:400;
text-decoration:none;
border-bottom:3px solid #191919;
padding-bottom:20px;     /*whatever css u put in hover put here */
 }
```

Hope this helps :)